# What is the difference between using "html{}" and "root:" pseudo-class while styling a css document?

Tags: html, css

I did some research on this topic but still these two seem to have an identical function in css, for example: *html { background: yellow; }* and *root: { background: yellow; }* give the same result. Can somebody confirm my pseudo thesis or eventually point out any differences? :D

Comment: The "root" is a common name for the  "document root", not depending on the language that is used. In HTML, the root pseudo is always the HTML element, so css for `root` and `html {}` are the same in css.